# change view from view will appear

Tags: ios, swift

I am checking if the user is logged in and if it is I want to go straight to the main menu (skipping login screen) right now i have this in the login viwillAppear

```
if currentUser != nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_success", sender: self)
    }
```

It does go into the if statement but it does not change views. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` is called when the view is not in the view hierarchy yet, which is a requirement for performing a segue.

Your options are to call it in `viewDidAppear`, though users will see the first screen before the transition, or perform that check before displaying the login screen.